# Use space as a delimiter with cut command

Tags: bash, unix, cut

I want to use space as a delimiter with the `cut` command.

What syntax can I use for this?

Comment: untrue, the man page for cut doesn't explain this and is, in general, not informative

Comment: Also, "info cut" is no improvement in this case.

Comment: @UncleZeiv: The `man` page doesn't explain this, because it has nothing to do with `cut` _specifically_ and everything to do with [how the _shell_ parses string literals](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) and with [how POSIX-compatible utilities parse option-arguments](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) _in general_.

Comment: @mklement0 if I recall, I was replying to a comment that has since been deleted, which was dismissing this question as being answered to in the man page, which was in my opinion "untrue", regardless of there being a good reason for it or not - now, while I concede that there might be a good reason for this lack of information, I still think that documentation without common usage examples is often at least irritating, when not outright useless

Comment: @UncleZeiv Got it; thanks for clarifying; given the interest in this question, it's fair to assume that the `man` page isn't enough.
Let's take a look: "`-d delim` Use `delim` as the field delimiter character instead of the tab character." (BSD `cut`, but the GNU version and the POSIX spec pretty much state the same).
Using a _shell_ to invoke `cut` - the typical case - therefore requires you to know how to _generally_ pass a space as an argument using _shell syntax_, which is arguably not the `cut` man page's job. Real-world examples always help, however, and the _GNU_ man page lacks them.

Comment: although the [selected answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/816824/199217) is technically correct, consider selecting the more [recent and comprehensive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29998195/199217) by @mklement0 as the canonical answer so that it filters to the top.

Answer (score 469, accepted):

```
cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Where 2 is the field number of the space-delimited field you want.

Comment: can you tell cut to use any number of a certain character as the delimiter, like in RegEx?  e.g. any number of spaces, e.g. \s+

Comment: @foampile No, I don't believe you can.

Comment: You can't use regexes with `cut`, but you can with `cuts` which tries to "fix" all of `cut` limitations: https://github.com/arielf/cuts

Comment: can you get every third space-delimted field? like `cut -d ' ' -f 3,6,9,12,15,18` without having to specify every number?

Comment: It's such a common use case to split on variable number of contiguous space it's a bit funny it's not dealt with - but following up on `cuts` sounds like it might be good.

Comment: I'll just point out, because commonly people viewing this answer are really looking for this instead, that `tr -s ' '` can be used in the pipeline to squash all occurrences of multiple spaces into one, making `cut -d ' '` suddenly really great for scenarios where you're getting variable numbers of spaces on the line because of justification. Actually available in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19069428/134044

Answer (score 257):

Usually if you use space as delimiter, you want to treat multiple spaces as one, because you parse the output of a command aligning some columns with spaces. (and the google search for that lead me here)

In this case a single `cut` command is not sufficient, and you need to use:

```
tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Or

```
awk '{print $2}'
```

This works because AWK's default input field separator is one or more whitespace characters; in regex terms, it's something like `[ \t]+`. The AWK solution has the added benefit of transparently handling leading/trailing spaces on the data row, whereas the `tr` + `cut` solution does not.

Comment: Yes! This should be the accepted answer, or at least included in the accepted answer. I can't remember ever trying to use cut on space separated data when I didn't have to normalize the spaces.

Comment: This is money. `tr` translates or deletes characters. The `-s` option replaces repeats with a single occurrence.

Comment: i'm on a mac and i couldn't get the `cut` or `tr` examples to work.  the `awk` example worked perfectly for what i was doing (splitting output with multiple spaces between columns)

Comment: @Alf47 It's unintuitive, given how most programs work, but `tr` is a "filter" and _only_ receives input on stdin and _only_ writes to stdout. It doesn't understand filename arguments, and you may not even get an error if you try to pass it a filename. This is just one of those things you learn. Your `cut` and `tr` should work basically the same as on Linux, or other Unices, so I'd encourage you to keep tinkering, and have a look at the EXAMPLES section of the man pages.

Comment: Yes, just use `awk`

Answer (score 61):

<sup>To complement the existing, helpful answers; tip of the hat to [QZ Support](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3196753/qz-support) for encouraging me to post a separate answer:</sup>

**Two distinct mechanisms** come into play here:

- (a) whether `cut` *itself* requires the delimiter (space, in this case) passed to the `-d` option to be a *separate argument* or whether it's acceptable to append it *directly* to `-d`.
- (b) how the *shell* generally parses arguments before passing them to the command being invoked.

(a) is answered by a quote from the [POSIX guidelines for utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) (emphasis mine)

> If the SYNOPSIS of a standard utility shows an option with a *mandatory* option-argument [...] a conforming application **shall use *separate* arguments for that option and its option-argument**. **However**, a conforming implementation shall ***also* permit applications to specify the option and option-argument in the same argument string without intervening  characters**.

In other words: In this case, **because `-d`'s option-argument is *mandatory***, **you can *choose* whether to specify the delimiter as**:

- (s) EITHER: a ***separate* argument**
- (d) OR: as a value ***directly attached* to `-d`**.

<sup>Note: The *GNU* implementation of `cut`, as found on many Linux distros by default, supports `--delimiter` as a more descriptive alias of `-d`. The same considerations apply as for `-d`, except that directly attaching the option-argument requires use of `=` as the separator, whereas *no* separator is used with `-d`; e.g.,

`echo 'one two' | cut --delimiter=' ' -f 1` vs. `echo 'one two' | cut -d' ' -f 1`</sup>

Once you've chosen (s) or (d), it is the *shell*'s string-literal parsing - (b) - that matters:

- With approach **(s)**, all of the following forms are EQUIVALENT:

  - `-d ' '`
  - `-d " "`
  - `-d \`  (`\<space>` is an escaped space to be used literally)
- With approach **(d)**, all of the following forms are EQUIVALENT:
- `-d' '`
- `-d" "`
- `"-d "`
- `'-d '`
- `d\`

The  equivalence is explained by the *shell*'s string-literal processing:

All **solutions above result in the *exact same string* (in each group) by the time `cut` sees them**:

- **(s)**: `cut` sees `-d`, as its *own* argument, followed by a *separate* argument that contains a space char - then without quotes or `\` prefix!.
- **(d)**: `cut` sees `-d` *plus* a space char - then without quotes or `\` prefix! - as part of the *same* argument.

The reason the forms in the respective groups are ultimately identical is twofold, based on **how the *shell* parses *string literals***:

- The shell allows literal to be specified *as is* through **a mechanism called *quoting***, which can take *several forms*:

  - **single-quoted** strings: the contents inside `'...'` is taken *literally* and forms a *single* argument
  - **double-quoted** strings: the contents inside `"..."` also forms a *single* argument, but is subject to *interpolation* (expands variable references such as `$var`, command substitutions (`$(...)` or `` `...` ``), or arithmetic expansions (`$(( ... ))`).
  - **`\`-quoting of *individual* characters**: a `\` preceding a single character causes that character to be interpreted as a literal.
- Quoting is complemented by **[quote removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)**, which means that once the shell has parsed a command line, it ***removes* the quote characters from the arguments** (any enclosing `'...'` or `"..."` or unquoted `\` instances) - thus, **the command being invoked never sees the quote characters**.

Comment: For cut from Gow only the option with double quote work: -d" ", -d " ", "-d ". All options with single quote or <space> not work.

Comment: @Frank, yes, it is the _shell_ that matters with respect to the quoting styles supported, and given that [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) runs on Windows, you either need to use `cmd.exe`'s syntax (`"`-quoting only, `^` as the escape char.) or PowerShell's syntax (`\`` as the escape char.)

Comment: With `--delimiter=` all of this explanation is moot, especially in shell scripts.

Comment: @mklement0 The MacOS is the least of most people's concerns doing shell programming. Using the edge case as the crux of your argument should bring into question why are you using proprietary tools. By the way, plenty of people run VirtualBox on the MacOS, so --delimiter= might be what they want as they do development in Linux.

Comment: It is also tagged as bash, and that is a GNU tool. Maybe install GNU tools and call it a day?

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge (This is an amended consolidation of my previous comments) The question is tagged `unix`, not `linux`, so it's important to use _portable_ syntax, and to point out where implementation-specific extensions are used (I've updated the answer to mention `--delimiter`).
More importantly, whether you use the POSIX-compliant `-d` or the GNU-specific `--delimiter` option _makes no difference with respect to the solution_ (the only difference is that direct attachment of the option-argument requires `=` as the separator in the latter case, as now noted in the answer).

Answer (score 49):

You can also say:

```
cut -d\  -f 2
```

Note that there are two spaces after the backslash.

Comment: The person who knows that '\' escapes the next character would be very careful to note what came next. Using '\' to escape space characters like this is a very common idiom.

Comment: @Jonathan Hartley  commonly most of the codes are unreadable indeed :)

Comment: From a linux/unix perspective, `\ ` was my first attempt and it worked.  I agree it is less obvious when compared to `' '`, but I'm sure many are glad to read it here as reassurance of behavior.  For a better understanding, please see @mklement0's comment below.

Comment: @JonathanHartley correction: "the *selfish* person who knows that '\' escapes the next character and *assumes* everybody else knows that also". For personal projects this does not apply, but in a team-setting, that assumption is a very dangerous (and potentially costly) one.

Comment: @EduardNicodei Oh I agree. We were talking about readers of the code ("who notices...?"), not authors. But also, on some teams it's fine to assume a certain level of proficiency. Depends on the environment.

Comment: And the person who knows that `-d` is followed by the delimiter could assume that \ is the delimiter :)

Answer (score 8):

I [just discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796979/read-line-containing-string-bash/29797044?noredirect=1#comment47722859_29797139) that you can also use `"-d "`:

```
cut "-d "
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello how are you
I am fine
$ cut "-d " -f2 a
how
am
```

Comment: Note that _from `cut`'s perspective_ all of the following are identical: `"-d "`, `'-d '`, `-d" "`,  `-d' '`, and `-d\<space>`: all forms directly append the option argument (a space) to the option (`-d`) and result in the _exact same string_ by the time `cut` sees them: a single argument containing d followed by a space, after the _shell_ has performed [quote removal](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html#Quote-Removal)

Comment: @mklement0's answer should be **the** answer.  It is the most comprehensive on this page (even though it is a comment).

Comment: @QZSupport: I appreciate the sentiment and the encouragement - it has inspired me to post my own answer with additional background information.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it easily with cut if the data has for example multiple spaces. I have found it useful to normalize input for easier processing. One trick is to use sed for normalization as below.

```
echo -e "foor\t \t bar" | sed 's:\s\+:\t:g' | cut -f2  #bar
```

Answer (score 3):

[scut](http://moo.nac.uci.edu/~hjm/scut_cols_HOWTO.html), a cut-like utility (smarter but slower I made) that can use any perl regex as a breaking token. Breaking on whitespace is the default, but you can also break on multi-char regexes, alternative regexes, etc.

```
scut -f='6 2 8 7' < input.file  > output.file
```

so the above command would break columns on whitespace and extract the (0-based) cols 6 2 8 7 in that order.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer (I admit somewhat confusing answer) that involves`sed`, regular expressions and capture groups:

- `\S*` - first word
- `\s*` - delimiter
- `(\S*)` - second word - captured
- `.*` - rest of the line

As a `sed` expression, the capture group needs to be escaped, i.e. `\(` and `\)`.

The `\1` returns a copy of the captured group, i.e. the second word.

```sh
$ echo "alpha beta gamma delta" | sed 's/\S*\s*\(\S*\).*/\1/'
beta
```

When you look at this answer, its somewhat confusing, and, you may think, why bother? Well, I'm hoping that some, may go "Aha!" and will use this pattern to solve some complex text extraction problems with a single `sed` expression.