# bash scripting - getting number output onto screen as result of previous command

Tags: bash, scripting, command-line, perforce

I am trying to automate the copying of changed files into a perforce changelist, but need help getting the generated changelist number. I assume this is probably a straight-forward thing for bash scripting - but I'm just not getting it yet!!...

Basically I execute the command

```
p4 change -o | sed 's/<enter description here>/This is my description./' | p4 change -i
```

As a result of this, I get output onto screen something like the line below (obviously the number changes)

```
Change 44152 created.
```

What I want, is to be able to capture the generated number into a variable I can then use in the rest of my script (to add future files to the same changelist etc)...

Can anyone please advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this

```
change=`p4 change -o | sed 's/<enter description here>/This is my description./' | p4 change -i|cut -d f2`

echo $change
```

**EDIT:** Per @Enigma last comment

If you want to use shell variable in sed command use doublr quote `""` instead single quote `''` around sed command. Like below

```
sed "s/<enter description here>/ updating $change form/"
```

Results in "updating 44152 form" ($change holds value 44152)

Comment: SO many ways to do this obviously, but I like this method, which is using @mkro sugestion, so thanks to you both! (you get the answer mark for the example ;) )

Comment: sorry, one further thing, I tried replacing the /This is my description./ with some dyanmic data eg /updating ${formName} form/ but i get the actual ${formName} string in the description. -- how can I escape this?? (nb, i tried without the {} also)

Comment: @FireEnigmaX, not sure whether you have already solved it; in case you haven't yet then see my edit

Comment: SOrry, yes I got it solved,I used the following: changeListNum=`p4 change -o | sed 's/<enter description here>/Commiting changes to '${ExportSubDir}' '${ArtifactName}'./' | p4 change -i|cut -d ' ' -f 2`

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the output of a command with the ` character.

```
myVariable=`myCommand`
```

You can use awk to get the 2nd column of data, the number part.

```
myVariable=`originalCommand|awk '{print $2}'`
```

Now myVariable will be your number, 44152.

Answer (score 2):

you could use cut. Here is another related stackoverflow entry:

[use space as a delimiter with cut command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816820/use-space-as-a-delimiter-with-cut-command)

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this

```
echo "Change 44152 created." | tr -d 'a-zA-Z .'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to get the last generated changelist, you can also type

```
variable=`p4 counter change`
```

but this will only work if no one else made a changelist after you made yours.