# List submodules in a Git repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a Git repository that has several submodules in it. How do I list the names of all the submodules after `git submodule init` has been run?

The `git submodule foreach` command could echo the names of the submodule, but that only works once they have been checked out which has not happened after the init step. There are more steps in the chain that need to happen before they can be checked out, and I don't want to have to hard-wire names of submodules into the script.

So is there a Git command to get the names of all currently registered, but not yet checked out submodules?

Comment: Super silly that it doesn't, but [Sandeep's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26083995/527489) shows that `git submodule` behaves as I expected a hypothetical `git submodule list` to behave - I just never thought to check what happens with *no* arguments to `git submodule`.  (Glad I tested that link, since I grabbed the wrong 'Share' link initially!)

Comment: I came here because `git submodule list` didn't exist and `git submodule help` didn't help (according to the latter, the solution, `git submodule`, is not valid usage).

Comment: Most of the answers (including the accepted one) list submodule `paths`, not `names` and break when they contain special characters. I tried to give an answer for both names and paths which should be safe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56912913/3215929

Answer (score 261, accepted):

You could use the same mechanism as `git submodule init` uses itself, namely, look at `.gitmodules`. This files enumerates each submodule path and the URL it refers to.

For example, from root of repository, `cat .gitmodules` will print contents to the screen (assuming you have `cat`).

Because .gitmodule files have the Git configuration format, you can use git config to parse those files:

```
git config --file .gitmodules --name-only --get-regexp path
```

Would show you all submodule entries, and with

```
git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp path | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

you would only get the submodule path itself.

Comment: But it doesn't print anything out on the console.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - you can print on the console, if you do `cat .gitmodules` in the repository root...

Comment: The `awk` part fails if you have spaces in the submodule path.

Comment: @Ikke I would like to retrieve a list of submodules including name, path and url. I tried the following Git command, but it doesn't return anything: git config --file=.gitmodules --get-regexp .*?submodule (.*)] path = (.*) url = (.*)

I tried git config --file=.gitmodules --get-regexp .*?(submodule).*?(path).*?(url) as well.

Perhaps you have a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Odrai If you just want everything, why don't you just specify `--list`? Like: `git config --file .gitmodules -l`

Comment: **WARNING: `awk` fails for submodules with spaces!**  The command should read **`git config -z --file .gitmodules --get-regexp '\.path$'  | sed -nz 's/^[^\n]*\n//p' | tr '\0' '\n'`** (you need a modern `sed` with `-z`).  This fails for **paths with Newlines in them** (they can be created with `git mv`).  If you want to be safe against these, leave away the `| tr '\0' '\n'` and use something like `... | while IFS='' read -d '' path; do ...` for further processing with bash.  This needs a modern bash which understands `read -d ''` (do not forget the space between `-d` and `''`).

Comment: If you have a path with a newline in it, a failing awk or sed will likely not be on top of your gigantic list of problems.

Comment: Just `awk '/path/{ print $NF }' .gitmodules` will do it.

Answer (score 216):

You can use `git submodule status` or optionally `git submodule status --recursive` if you want to show nested submodules.

From the Git documentation:

> Show the status of the submodules. This will print the SHA-1 of the
>   currently checked out commit for each submodule, along with the
>   submodule path and the output of git describe for the SHA-1. Each
>   SHA-1 will be prefixed with - if the submodule is not initialized, +
>   if the currently checked out submodule commit does not match the SHA-1
>   found in the index of the containing repository and U if the submodule
>   has merge conflicts.

Comment: Just run `git submodule update --init --recursive` to initialise all submodule.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky just read at Stefaan's comment: this kind of commands do _not work if the submodules are not initialised yet_. No output = no submodule (empty list).

Comment: This should definitely be marked as _best answer_ for using a simple and native `git`-based command without any help from bash. And this solution is elegant in the way that it runs well at any point of the working copy (but the submodules themselves of course, for which the result applies directly to themselves).

Comment: As Sandeep Gill's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26083995/328817) says, `git submodule` with no arguments is the same as `git submodule status`, so you can save yourself typing 7 characters ;-)

Comment: @Sam They aren't quite the same since `git submodule status --recursive` works, but `git submodule --recursive` doesn't. Those 7 characters do buy you something. It depends on your needs though.

Answer (score 88):

The following command will list the submodules:

```
git submodule--helper list
```

The output is something like this:

```
<mode> <sha1> <stage> <location>
```

Note: It requires Git 2.7.0 or above.

Comment: Great!. Where is this command documented. Works on Git for Windwos but cannot find any docs on https://git-scm.com/

Comment: `git ls-files --stage | grep ^160000` (from Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29325219) seems to produce the same result, so perhaps this is a good replacement if you need to be compatible to older gits.

Comment: Pay attention to `--` double dashes in `submodule--helper`

Comment: I want to see which branch each submodule is on, how do I do that?

Comment: This one is not recursive.

Comment: Getting only the submodules
`git submodule--helper list | awk '{ print $NF }'`

Answer (score 67):

To return just the names of the registered submodules, you can use this command:

```
grep path .gitmodules | sed 's/.*= //'
```

Think of it as `git submodule --list` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Instead, use `perl -ne '/^\s*path =\s*(.*)/ and push(@submods, $1); END { print(join("\n", sort(@submods)));}' "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.gitmodules"` which compared to this answer (1) works from any subdirectory (though not inside a submodule); (2) sorts the submodules by name; and (3) ignores commented lines in .gitmodules.

Comment: And it's memorable to boot!

Comment: Note that this is very sloppy way of doing it, as `path` might be present in the submodule name (`git submodule add https://github.com/commercialhaskell/path.git`).  But you probably already knew that before.  If you want to access `.gitconfig` from anywhere in a worktree or need to run this in a `--bare` repository, you can use something like `git cat-file -p HEAD:.gitmodules | ...`.  If you need to refer to the "staged" file, you can do `git cat-file -p :.gitmodules | ...`, however this needs a git `index` to be present.

Answer (score 41):

Use:

```
$ git submodule
```

It will list all the submodules in the specified Git repository.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate answer of the two other answers that mention `git submodule [status]` (note that `status` is implied if omitted, so this is the same).

Comment: Doesn't always work. `fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'bla-bla/foo-bar'`. First you have to delete all inner repositories that are not submoduled yet.

Comment: Best answer ( •̀ ω •́ )✧

Comment: Note that if you want to use the `--recursive` flag, you have to explicitly add the `status` command: `git submodule status --recursive` works, but `git submodule --recursive` doesn't.

Answer (score 21):

I use this:

```
git config --list|egrep ^submodule
```

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky just read at Stefaan's comment: _This does not work if the submodules are not initialised yet_. No output = no submodule (empty list).

Comment: This is exaclty what I needed. It shows the subfolders of the submodules and the urls of their remotes.

Answer (score 19):

I noticed that the command provided in an answer to this question gave me the information I was looking for:

*[No submodule mapping found in .gitmodule for a path that's not a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185365/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodule-for-a-path-thats-not-a-submodule)*

```
git ls-files --stage | grep 160000
```

Comment: This answer is nice and clean, are there any disadvantages compared to [mholm815's answer parsing .gitmodules](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17157444/994153)?

Comment: BTW, if you just want the names of the submodules, use `git ls-files --stage | grep 160000 | perl -ne 'chomp;split;print "$_[3]\n"'`

Comment: This worked for me since I had no `.gimodules` or anything in `.git/config`. (I'm not sure how it happen, I got the repository in this state. It was some mistake, so solution was `git rm`.)

Comment: It's working with bare repos. Unlike .gitmodules solution.

Comment: This is the best answer. Just a small nit: `grep "^160000 "` would be slightly more robust.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't mind operating only on initialized submodules, you can use `git submodule foreach` to avoid text parsing.

```
git submodule foreach --quiet 'echo $name'
```

Comment: This answer is unique in that it only works for submodules that have been initialized. Depending on what you need, this might be desired behavior (but it might also be unexpected and undesired.)

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
git submodule | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: This seems to produce the same output as http://stackoverflow.com/a/23490756/895245 but is shorter.

Comment: Downvoted.  This command is dangerous, because it fails for a submodule i.E. named **`test (master)`** (name with a space followed by parentheses) , which **is a valid submodule name**.  The command also cannot be fixed, because git either prints `module` or `module (branch)`.  And it is even worse, as this command is not porcellain, so the output of the command may change in future without prior notice.

Comment: If you want to get the name of submodule with spaces after clone, you can 

`git submodule | awk -F' ' '{ print $2,$NF }'`

If you have tags in submodules, you can cut it:

`git submodule | awk -F' ' '{ print $2,$NF }' | awk -F'(' '{ print $1 }'`

or 

`cat .gitmodules | awk -F '"' '{print $2}' | xargs`

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
git ls-files --stage | grep ^160000
```

It is based on this great article: *[Understanding Git Submodules](https://web.archive.org/web/20200225152945/https://www.speirs.org/blog/2009/5/11/understanding-git-submodules.html)*

It must read `grep ^160000`.

Comment: `git ls-files --stage | grep ^160000` seems to produce the same output as `git submodule--helper list` from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40877379

Answer (score 11):

To list all submodules by name:

`git submodule --quiet foreach --recursive 'echo $name'`

Comment: The best answer ever out of so many long answers. How do you know that the output of git submodule contains a column that is called "name"? I am wondering.

Answer (score 10):

Display ALL info about each submodule using built-in git functions:

```
git submodule foreach -q git config -l
```

Or just URL-s:

```
git submodule foreach -q git config remote.origin.url
```

Stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913701/how-to-change-the-remote-repository-for-a-git-submodule#comment17230685_914090).

Answer (score 9):

I use this one:

```
git submodule status | cut -d' ' -f3-4
```

Output (path + version):

```
tools/deploy_utils (0.2.4)
```

Comment: The disadvantage I see of this version is that it is slow.  It seems to be doing some kind of status checking on each submodule, maybe close to a second per submodule on my machine, so on projects with many submodules this is not a good solution, or if it should be run from a script etc.

Answer (score 6):

Just a straight list of submodules:

```
git submodule--helper list | cut -d$'\t' -f 2
```

Answer (score 5):

> **Just** the *submodule paths* please, ma'am...

```
git config --list | grep \^submodule | cut -f 2 -d .
```

> ```
> Vendor/BaseModel
> Vendor/ObjectMatcher
> Vendor/OrderedDictionary
> Vendor/_ObjC
> Vendor/XCodeHelpers
> ```

Comment: While this probably is a completely valid answer for the question, here are some caveats:  This only works for submodules which do not contain dots in their name.  A dot is completely valid in module names.  It does not restrict to `.url` keys, so other entries might show up as well (usually there are none, but shit happens).  You should use `--local` here, because you do not want to see `--global` and `--system` settings.  And last to note, because it might be overlooked, it only works for submodules, which are already present in `.git/config` (like after `git submodule init`, see question).

Answer (score 5):

[`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) allows to specify a config file.
And `.gitmodules` *is* a config file.

So, with the help of "[use space as a delimiter with cut command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/816824/6309)":

```
git config --file=.gitmodules --get-regexp ^^submodule.*\.path$ | cut -d " " -f 2
```

That will list only the paths, one per declared submodule.

As [Tino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/490291/tino) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641469/list-submodules-in-a-git-repository/31695872#comment84215697_12641787):

> - This fails for submodules with **spaces** in it.
> - submodule paths may contain **newlines**, as in
>
>   ```
>   git submodule add https://github.com/hilbix/bashy.git "sub module"
>     git mv 'sub module' $'sub\nmodule'
>   ```

As a more robust alternative, Tino proposes:

> ```
> git config -z --file .gitmodules --get-regexp '\.path$' | \
>   sed -nz 's/^[^\n]*\n//p' | \
>   tr '\0' '\n'
> ```
>
> For paths with newlines in them (they can be created with `git mv`), leave away the `| tr '\0' '\n'` and use something like `... | while IFS='' read -d '' path; do ...` for further processing with bash.
>   This needs a modern bash which understands `read -d ''` (do not forget the space between `-d and ''`).

Comment: hmmm... "there must be a better way" are my immediate thoughts

Comment: guess i could alias that command in bash profile etc. thanks anyhow.

Comment: This fails for submodules with spaces in it.  Also note, that paths may contain Newlines (`git submodule add https://github.com/hilbix/bashy.git "sub module"; git mv 'sub module' $'sub\nmodule'`).  See my comment to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12641787) which is very similar to yours.

Comment: @Tino Good points. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 4):

In my version of Git <sup>[1]</sup>, every Git submodule has a `name` and a `path`. They don't necessarily have to be the same <sup>[2]</sup>. Getting both in a reliable way, without checking out the submodules first (`git update --init`), is a tricky bit of shell wizardry.

## Get a list of submodule `names`

I didn't find a way how to achieve this using `git config` or any other `git` command. Therefore we are back to regex on `.gitmodules` (super ugly). But it seems to be somewhat safe since `git` limits the possible code space allowed for submodule `names`. In addition, since you probably want to use this list for further shell processing, the solution below separate entries with `NULL`-bytes (`\0`).

```sh
$ sed -nre \
  's/^\[submodule \"(.*)\"]$/\1\x0/p' \
  "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.gitmodules" \
| tr -d '\n' \
| xargs -0 -n1 printf "%b\0"
```

And in your script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -rd '' submodule_name; do
  echo submodule name: "${submodule_name}"
done < <(
  sed -nre \
    's/^\[submodule \"(.*)\"]$/\1\x0/p' \
    "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.gitmodules" \
  | tr -d '\n' \
  | xargs -0 -n1 printf "%b\0"
)
```

*Note*: `read -rd ''` requires `bash` and won't work with `sh`.

## Get a list of submodule `paths`

In my approach I try **not** to process the output from `git config --get-regexp` with `awk`, `tr`, `sed`, ... but instead pass it a zero byte separated back to `git config --get`. This is to avoid problems with newlines, spaces and other special characters (e.g. Unicode) in the submodule `paths`. In addition, since you probably want to use this list for further shell processing, the solution below separate entries with `NULL`-bytes (`\0`).

```sh
$ git config --null --file .gitmodules --name-only --get-regexp '\.path$' \
| xargs -0 -n1 git config --null --file .gitmodules --get
```

For example, in a Bash script you could then:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -rd '' submodule_path; do
  echo submodule path: "${submodule_path}"
done < <(
  git config --null --file .gitmodules --name-only --get-regexp '\.path$' \
  | xargs -0 -n1 git config --null --file .gitmodules --get
)
```

*Note*: `read -rd ''` requires `bash` and won't work with `sh`.

---

## Footnotes

### <sup>[1]</sup> Git version

```sh
$ git --version
git version 2.22.0
```

### <sup>[2]</sup> Submodule with diverging `name` and `path`

Set up test repository:

```sh
$ git init test-name-path
$ cd test-name-path/
$ git checkout -b master
$ git commit --allow-empty -m 'test'
$ git submodule add ./ submodule-name
Cloning into '/tmp/test-name-path/submodule-name'...
done.
$ ls
submodule-name

$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "submodule-name"]
    path = submodule-name
    url = ./
```

Move submodule to make `name` and `path` diverge:

```sh
$ git mv submodule-name/ submodule-path

$ ls
submodule-path

$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "submodule-name"]
    path = submodule-path
    url = ./

$ git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp '\.path$'
submodule.submodule-name.path submodule-path
```

### Testing

Set up test repository:

```sh
$ git init test
$ cd test/
$ git checkout -b master
$ git commit --allow-empty -m 'test'
$
$ git submodule add ./ simplename
Cloning into '/tmp/test/simplename'...
done.
$
$ git submodule add ./ 'name with spaces'
Cloning into '/tmp/test/name with spaces'...
done.
$
$ git submodule add ./ 'future-name-with-newlines'
Cloning into '/tmp/test/future-name-with-newlines'...
done.
$ git mv future-name-with-newlines/ 'name
> with
> newlines'
$
$ git submodule add ./ 'name-with-unicode-'
Cloning into '/tmp/test/name-with-unicode-'...
done.
$
$ git submodule add ./ sub/folder/submodule
Cloning into '/tmp/test/sub/folder/submodule'...
done.
$
$ git submodule add ./ name.with.dots
Cloning into '/tmp/test/name.with.dots'...
done.
$
$ git submodule add ./ 'name"with"double"quotes'
Cloning into '/tmp/test/name"with"double"quotes'...
done.
$
$ git submodule add ./ "name'with'single'quotes"
Cloning into '/tmp/test/name'with'single'quotes''...
done.
$ git submodule add ./ 'name]with[brackets'
Cloning into '/tmp/test/name]with[brackets'...
done.
$ git submodule add ./ 'name-with-.path'
Cloning into '/tmp/test/name-with-.path'...
done.
```

`.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "simplename"]
    path = simplename
    url = ./
[submodule "name with spaces"]
    path = name with spaces
    url = ./
[submodule "future-name-with-newlines"]
    path = name\nwith\nnewlines
    url = ./
[submodule "name-with-unicode-"]
    path = name-with-unicode-
    url = ./
[submodule "sub/folder/submodule"]
    path = sub/folder/submodule
    url = ./
[submodule "name.with.dots"]
    path = name.with.dots
    url = ./
[submodule "name\"with\"double\"quotes"]
    path = name\"with\"double\"quotes
    url = ./
[submodule "name'with'single'quotes"]
    path = name'with'single'quotes
    url = ./
[submodule "name]with[brackets"]
    path = name]with[brackets
    url = ./
[submodule "name-with-.path"]
    path = name-with-.path
    url = ./
```

#### Get list of submodule `names`

```sh
$ sed -nre \
  's/^\[submodule \"(.*)\"]$/\1\x0/p' \
  "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.gitmodules" \
| tr -d '\n' \
| xargs -0 -n1 printf "%b\0" \
| xargs -0 -n1 echo submodule name:
submodule name: simplename
submodule name: name with spaces
submodule name: future-name-with-newlines
submodule name: name-with-unicode-
submodule name: sub/folder/submodule
submodule name: name.with.dots
submodule name: name"with"double"quotes
submodule name: name'with'single'quotes
submodule name: name]with[brackets
submodule name: name-with-.path
```

#### Get list of submodule `paths`

```sh
$ git config --null --file .gitmodules --name-only --get-regexp '\.path$' \
| xargs -0 -n1 git config --null --file .gitmodules --get \
| xargs -0 -n1 echo submodule path:
submodule path: simplename
submodule path: name with spaces
submodule path: name
with
newlines
submodule path: name-with-unicode-
submodule path: sub/folder/submodule
submodule path: name.with.dots
submodule path: name"with"double"quotes
submodule path: name'with'single'quotes
submodule path: name]with[brackets
submodule path: name-with-.path
```

Answer (score 4):

Let say you have all currently registered, but not yet checked out submodules like below:

```
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule ".github/workflows/packages"]
        path = .github/workflows/packages
        url = https://github.com/MarketLeader/Packages
[submodule ".github/workflows/builders"]
        path = .github/workflows/builders
        url = https://github.com/chetabahana/runner
[submodule "docs"]
        path = docs
        url = https://github.com/eq19/lexer
```

Here is the Git command to get on the **root of repository**:

```
$ git submodule foreach -q '[[ "$sm_path" == */* ]] || git config remote.origin.url'
https://github.com/eq19/lexer
```

And here is the Git command to get list on a **specific path**:

```
$ git submodule foreach -q '[[ ! "$sm_path" == .github/* ]] || git config remote.origin.url'
https://github.com/chetabahana/runner
https://github.com/MarketLeader/Packages
```

Of course, you may change `git config remote.origin.url` with other commands as you wish.

By the way I am using git version 2.38.1

[image: get the names of allsubmodules]

Comment: Nicely done. More detailed than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65901740/6309)

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't any `.gitmodules` file, but a submodules configuration exists in `.git/modules/`:

```
find .git/modules/ -name config -exec grep url {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get path

```
grep url .gitmodules | sed 's/.*= //'
```

To get names as in repos

```
grep path .gitmodules | sed 's/.*= //'
```

Answer (score 1):

This works even before `git submodule init`, as it reads `.gitmodules`:

```
cat .gitmodules | grep path | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to parse Git submodule names from .gitmodules without the need for sed or fancy IFS settings. :-)

```sh
#!/bin/env bash

function stripStartAndEndQuotes {
  temp="${1%\"}"
  temp="${temp#\"}"
  echo "$temp"
}

function getSubmoduleNames {
  line=$1
  len=${#line} # Get line length
  stripStartAndEndQuotes "${line::len-1}" # Remove last character
}

while read line; do
  getSubmoduleNames "$line"
done < <(cat .gitmodules | grep "\[submodule.*\]" | cut -d ' ' -f 2-)
```

Comment: Plus, this solution seems to handle the escaped double quotes example correctly whereas the above solution produces an escaped output. Which may not be correct in some cases. ;-)

Comment: "above" and "below" does not really work in a voting based sort order.

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative is as show in one [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12641787/4934640) by [Tino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/490291):

```bash
git config --null --file .gitmodules --get-regexp "\.path\$" | \
sed -nz "s/^[^\\n]*\n//p" | \
xargs --null rm -v;
```

But `--null/-z` option is not available for sed or xargs on BusyBox. Then, this is the best alternative I could come up (where xargs does not break on spaces):

```bash
grep "^\s*path\s*=" .gitmodules | \
sed -e "s/.*=\s*\"*//" -e "s/\"*\s*\$//" | \
xargs -n 1 -I mark rm -v "mark";
```

But it has a drawback, as `xargs` is called without `--null` and we are using `-I mark`, it is eating leading whitespaces. To fix it, do not use `xargs` and write the names to a file:

```bash
grep "^\s*path\s*=" .gitmodules | \
sed -e "s/.*=\s*\"*//" -e "s/\"*\s*\$//" > tempfilefordanmxargsmotherbroked.txt;
while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo ".$line."
done <"tempfilefordanmxargsmotherbroked.txt"
rm "tempfilefordanmxargsmotherbroked.txt"
```

- Correction: `xargs` on BusyBox is not removing leading whitespaces, but the full version is.