# What is stored in bare repositories regarding submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-bare

I'm trying to write a tool that inspects some git repositories.

I wondered what information is stored in a bare repository that regards submodules?

So far I assume that it's only the `.gitmodules` file. Would be nice if anyone could confirm this.

Comment: Related: [List submodules in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641469/list-submodules-in-a-git-repository)

Comment: Even more related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018979/get-bare-repository-submodule-hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018979/get-bare-repository-submodule-hash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, `.gitmodules` is a file within the repository, you can't directly access it within a bare repo, but you [can obtain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30329683/1536976) it with `git show HEAD:.gitmodules`.

Comment: I think I could if I browse the objects of tree type and look for an entry of type blob named `.gitmodules`, but that's not what I want anyway.

Comment: I wouldn't really have called that direct. Plus you'd need to parse the tree to figure out *which* blob you wanted (assuming it had ever been changed).

Comment: I'd start with the tree of the HEAD. But that's just a theoretical exercise since I don't want to do that anyway.