# How to list existing branches of a git submodule (without initializing it first)?

Tags: git, branch, git-submodules

I have a project with lots of submodules for some specific reason. I just want to know which branches exist for each submodule. I know that I could initialize each submodule with

```
git submodule update --init
```

and perform a

```
git ls-remote --heads {URL}
```

on each submodule to get the currently existing branches of that submodule (git branch -r also lists already deleted branches). But since our project exists of many submodules the initialization above needs a lot of time on the first run. Is there a way to get the existing branches without initializing the submodules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in "[List submodules in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12641469/6309)", you could get the url directly from the `.gitmodules` file.

```
grep url .gitmodules | sed 's/.*= //'
```

Once you have extracted the url, you can do the `git ls-remote --heads {URL}` without having to initialize the submodules.