# How do I `git add -u` except new commits in submodules?

Tags: git

My current `git status` is:

```
modified:   Gemfile
modified:   Gemfile.lock
modified:   ... many more files
modified:   submodule_1 (new commits)
modified:   submodule_2 (new commits)
modified:   ... many more updated submodules ...
```

## How do I `git add -u` except new commits in submodules?

What I want to achieve is an equivalent of `git add -u`, then `git reset HEAD submodule_1 submodule_2 ... submodule_n`, or an equivalent of `git add -u Gemfile Gemfile.lock ...all other files that are not submodules...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once git add -u is done, you would need to reset all submodule paths.
As documented in "[List submodules in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12641787/6309)"

```
git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp path | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs git reset --
```

This would list all submodule paths and do a `git reset` on each one.

A similar idea, [from this gist](https://gist.github.com/eLod/1384566):

```
for i in `git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp path | cut -d" " -f2` ; do git reset -- $i ; done
```

Final solution, a bashrc/zshrc funnction that does `git add -u` and resets submodules:

```
gitaddus() {
  git add -u
  git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp path | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs git reset -- >/dev/null
  git status
}
```

(There's still a room for improvements, e.g. check which submodules are already added to the index so we don't `git reset` these.)

Comment: @Nowaker OK, I got mixed up. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I've made it a function and added `git add -u`.

Comment: @Nowaker Great! you can add it as a function, or you can make a bash script (even on Windows) called `git-addus` (no file extension), which you can then call as `git addus`. If `git-addus` is in your `$PATH` or `%PATH%`, it will be executed as a bash by Git, when called as `git addus`. This works for any script called `git-xxx`.