# git submodule checked out in the wrong branch

Tags: git

In my git repository I have two branches `master` and `legacy`. I have added the following `.gitmodules` file to my legacy branch. `master` branch does not have a `.gitmodules` file.However the git submodule is getting checked out in `master` branch. In the `legacy` branch nothing is getting checked out.

My .gitmodules file .

```
[submodule "build"]
    path = build
    url = git@git.gitlabs.com:Karthik.Sharma/build.git
    branch = 0.4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It depends on the sequence of operations you performed with git, which you should reveal as part of the question. Nothing is checked out on legacy is expected, as submodule only creates a link to a specific commit, or a branch. What happens to your master branch is unknown based on what you posted.

Comment: Submodules don't really use branches at all: the specific commit, if any, for a submodule is stored as a hash ID in the commit of the superproject. You extract the superproject's commit as usual (e.g., `git checkout <name>`) and then instruct Git to wrench the submodule over to the subproject-commit-hash-ID saved in that superproject commit (`git submodule update`, or similar). The submodule repository is left in "detached HEAD" mode.

Answer (score 0):

First, after adding the .gitmodules files, you should make a `git submodule update --init` in order to force the submodule to be checked out.

Second, [check the nature of the `build` folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24122304/6309) in the master branch.

```
git ls-files --stage | grep 160000
```

If you don't see `build` in the result, that means it is a regular folder (not a submodule).