# Why can't I find remote branches on the subfolder of my cloned repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, branch, subdirectory

I can't find remote branches on the subfolder of my cloned repository.

Context : I'm building a website using Ruby on Rails. So, I have the default blog folder (containing files generated by Ruby on Rails) inside folders which act as dividers (for example to separate backend and frontend). I cloned the project folder (root) and created a new branch there. The structure of the folders is project/code/backend/blog.

The codes that I used ...

1. `git clone https://github.com/username/project`
2. `cd project`
3. `git branch features`
4. `git branch -av` => showed the existence of the features branch.
5. `cd code/backend/blog`
6. `git branch -av` => showed nothing.

Comment: What repo? Is the folder a submodule?

Comment: No, I only cloned the project folder which consists code/backend/blog. As far as I know, a submodule is a repository is it? Btw, thanks for your prompt reply!

Comment: But that clone might include a submobule: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe umm, sorry I don't quite understand. But the context is I'm building a website using Ruby on Rails. So, I have the default blog (containing files generated by Ruby on Rails) folder inside folders which act as dividers (for example to separate backend and frontend). I cloned the project folder (root) and created a new branch there. Thanks!

Comment: We can't help without more information.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you mean I should check if my project includes a submodule first? Sorry, I'm very new at git!

Answer (score 0):

As described in comments, it is likely that `code/backend/blog` may be a git submodule. To verify that, run:

```
 git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp path | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

in project's root directory.

If `code/backend/blog` (or one of its subdirectories) is on the list of values returned by this command, then it is a submodule (or is a part of a submodule), and therefore it has separate branches.

More on listing submodules here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12641787/11116436