# How to list the URL for all Git submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

The "git remote get-url origin" can be used to fetch the location of the remote. How do I do the same for all the submodules?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run the command for every submodule:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git remote get-url origin
```

Answer (score 3):

For a different approach which also illistrates how to get the URL of a single named submodule:

```bash
for submodule in $(git submodule | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs)
do
  git config --file=.gitmodules submodule.${submodule}.url
done
```

Answer (score 2):

this works without `git submodule update --init`

```bash
git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp '\.url$' | awk '{print $2}'
```

based on [List submodules in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641469/list-submodules-in-a-git-repository)