# cut -d not working as expected

Tags: bash

I'm trying to parse a result from lsof utility in terminal.

```
lsof -n -i | grep 192.168.0.105:58281 | cut -d" " -f2
```

Instead of returning the second column separated by spaced, the output is an empty line.
What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space between `-d` and `" "` ? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816820/use-space-as-a-delimiter-with-cut-command) for the thing you wanna get.

Comment: No, there is no need in a space.

Comment: Are you sure the first part (lsof -n -i and the grep) is returning anything? When I run your code (with an adjusted grep) I do get some output.

Comment: I think there should be a space as well as between `-f` and `2`.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Actually if I try -f7 it returns what I want.
Something is messed up with the spaces, I just can't understand why.

Comment: @KlausPrinoth spaces don't play here any role. Please check before posting here.

Comment: Ok sorry, you're right, anyway couldt it be a bug because there are multiple spaces as delimiter in the output of `lsof`?

Comment: I'm suspecting that "multiple spaces" are indeed the root of the problem. However I'm not sure how to workaround it in a "robust enough" way.

Comment: I've found something [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4483833/4999641)

Comment: @KlausPrinoth, exactly what I looked for, thanks!
You can write here an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flaw in your code is that `lsof` outputs multiple spaces as delimiter and `cut` treats all these spaces as different colums.
To achieve what you want you can use `tr -s ' '` to delete the redundant spaces. So you could use something like this:

```
lsof -n -i | grep 192.168.0.105:58281 | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

`cut` considers each space as a separate token. So it prints the space between the 1st and 2nd column.

You could do the same using `awk`:

```
lsof -n -i | grep 192.168.0.105:58281 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The output columns from `lsof` are delimited by one *or more* spaces. So you need to “squeeze” (`-s` or `--squeeze-repeats`) them in order for `cut` to be able to pick out columns.

This can be done by simply adding a `tr` into your pipeline:

```
lsof -n -i |tr -s ' ' | grep  ...
```

But `awk` is probably a better solution than `cut`/`tr` with its ability to more intelligently parse fields. Furthermore, you can eliminate the `grep` (which wasn’t treating `.` as you mean without `\`-escaping) with an Awk regex:

```
lsof -n -i | awk '/192\.168\.0\.105:58281/ {print $2}'
```